# Please fix message for last rejected flag

Tags: bug, flags, declined-flags, wording

My last flag has been declined by moderator, and now I see a message:

> Your last flag was declined - please review it before flagging this post!

for **ALL** new flags. These new flags are currently in pending state. So I think notice message should be fixed to focus on last **processed** flag, not pending ones.

Comment: The whole idea behind the message could be better, really. "Some of your previous flags were declined - please review your previous flags before raising other flags!" avoids the issue of pending flags being uncounted in a progression, and really hits that SE want user to check their flag history for explanation before doing more.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro that's not [solved my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQ4vL.jpg), but it's a exact duplicate, true!

Comment: @alexolut There were 3 or 4 different posts about this issue, so I thought it made sense to redirect them all to one place.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro this will require to accept "solved my problem" item 2 or 3 times :)